# `dragend` is not getting called in my d3 application

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code...

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
             .on("dragstart", function(d, i){
                console.log("Started dragging "+d.x+":"+JSON.stringify(i));
             })
             .on("dragend", function(){
                console.log("Ended dragging");
             });
....
var circle = elemEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d){
                   // return d.r
                   return 30;
                 })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("fill", "blue")
      .call(drag)
```

I see the dragstart getting called but the dragend console message is never shown

Update:

Looks like the actual problem comes from this...

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-600).linkDistance(80).size([width, height]);
var elemEnter = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes).enter()
      .append("g")
      .call(force.drag);
```

When I add the `call(drag)` to the end of this, it logs as expected but does not allow movement.

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/9fb0jq04/

Comment: See update for more info still working on the JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the parent `g` overriding the drag event somehow on the child `circle`. If I added `force.drag().on("dragend", dragended);` it seems to work as expected.